# JS Variables affected each other resulted problem in Nested For loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, concurrency, promise, async-await

I want to translate some json files using [google-translate-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api) , it's a Promise.

I write some code like below, it works well only use await, means no concurrent.

```
(async function (){
    let file = fs.readdirSync(files);
    let k = file.length;
    for (let e=0;e<k;e++){
        await tranAsync(baseOriginal,file[e],fromTo).then( some code );
    }
})();
var material = some JSON object;
var fromTo =  {from: 'en', to: 'jp'};
async function tranAsync(material, fromTo){
    let cm = ["vedio","audio"];
    for (x in cm){
        for (let i=0; i<material[cm[x]].length; i++){
            material[cm[x]][i].description_ZH = await translate(material[cm[x]][i].description,fromTo); 
        }
    }
    return material;
}
```

If I remove the await before tranAsync Promise, means concurrent enabled, here is the problem: the script will not work well, some translated materials will be undefined. I tried debugger to find out why, It seems that is because variables **i** or some other variables were affected by each other. For example, if the script starting to process json file-10, in the loop x = audio of the first for, actually, the length of file-10.audio is 0, but even the i big than 0, like 2, the translation line will still work, then it throws out an error, shows that file-10.audio[2].description is undefined.

I am a beginner in the program, this really disappointed me. Thank you very much for your help. It will save me.

Comment: For one issue, change `for (x in cm){` to `for (let x in cm){` so you aren't accidentally using a global `x`.  Even better, change it to `for (let x of cm) {` and then change `cm[x]` to just `x` inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved the problem. Really thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `for (x in cm){` to `for (let x in cm){` so you aren't accidentally using a global `x` which will get overwritten between multiple calls to this function (because of the asynchronous operations here).

Even better, change it to `for (let x of cm) {` and then change `cm[x]` to just `x` inside the loop.

FYI, if you run your code in strict mode, then this type of error is flagged for you automatically.

Comment: really appreciate